# Does unsetting PHP Session variable maintain the key?

Tags: php, ajax, session, unset

I may be missing something here, but I have an ajax call to a php script that sets some session vars.The ajax call is hitting the script page concurrently, since its sending files to upload one at a time to the same script (Kartik Input)

After a specified number of calls, I am check if array_key_exists on a specified key, and then UNSETTING the values in the session.

However, the array_key_exists conditional continues to be run, even when the session values are supposed to be UNSET! Now I scoured this place to find specific instances of keys unset vs values unset, and none gives me an answer for my situation. Is it possible that the concurrent requests from ajax is hitting the script faster than PHP can UNSET these variables?

Here is the code:
I am dying on the result to see the session values after I unset them. They're all still there, alive and well.. What am I missing here? I don't want to destroy the session because this will log my user out... so I have to use unset.

```
if(array_key_exists('msg_file_count', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('msg_insert_count', $_SESSION))
{

    if($_SESSION['msg_file_count'] == $_SESSION['msg_insert_count'])
    {
        // Unset the session vars
        unset($_SESSION['msg_rowid']);
        unset($_SESSION['msg_insert_count']);
        unset($_SESSION['msg_filenames']);
        unset($_SESSION['msg_file_count']);
    }
$result = array('in'=>'msg_file_count', 'session'=> $_SESSION);
    die(json_encode($result));
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that `$_SESSION['msg_rowid']` still exists after unsetting it?'

Comment: Yes, they still exist. So the conditional its wrapped in, checks to see if the number of uploads (lets say 2) has been reached, at which point I want to clear everything.

Comment: What happens if you change the value of of the session variable to something else. Does it retain the new information?

Comment: Before calling die, can you please try adding [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

Comment: Ok Ill try session_write_close()... what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Write the session data and close the session handler.

Comment: @Difster If I set the value  to something else, then my conditional check above.. the array_key_exists will still run true. I only want it to be true only for as long as I want the keys around. I pretty much want to totally remove their existence..

Comment: @Rogelio - I just meant as a way to test how your session data is performing in your server. I realize the condition will still be met.

Comment: Are you certain though that the conditions of the 2nd if statement are being met?

Comment: @Scuzzy I added that line.. tried again. No luck my friend. The session counter just keeps going up. Does session_start() not revive the variables? I have that at the top of my script.. but I need it there because I need to create them the first time through the script.. I think Ajax calls is whats really complicating things here, otherwise it would be pretty straightforward, at least I think  so

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the provided code.

Comment: It seems a forced delay helped solve the problem. The only thing I can think of is that the ajax req was happening faster than PHP could unset vars? Makes no sense to me and I guess Ill never know the answer